# Eclipse/PyDev treats newlines pasted into its console as instructions, but I want it to parse them as part of a long string

Tags: python, eclipse, pydev

I am working on a Python script to automate some repetitive text-fiddling tasks I need to do.  I use PyDev as a plugin for Eclipse as my IDE.

I need the script to accept user input pasted from the clipboard.  The input will typically be many lines long, with many newline characters included.

I currently have the script asking for input as follows:

```
oldTableString = raw_input('Paste text of old table here:\n')
```

The console correctly displays the prompt and waits for user input.  However, once I paste text into the console, it appears to interpret any newline characters in the pasted text as presses of the enter button, and executes the code as if the only input it received was the first line of the pasted text (before the first newline character), followed by a press of the enter key (which it interprets as a cue that I'm done giving it input).

I've confirmed that it's only reading the first line of the input via the following line:

```
print oldTableString
```

...which, as expected, prints out only the first line of whatever I paste into the console.

---

How can I get Eclipse to recognize that I want it to parse the entirety of what I paste into the console, newlines included, as a single string?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

```py
text = ""

tmp = raw_input("Enter text:\n")

while tmp != "":
    text += tmp + "\n"
    tmp = raw_input()

print text
```

This works but you have to press enter one more time.

Comment: This does not appear to work...it does not require an extra enter press, it just prints the first line of whatever I paste into the console, just like my code.

Comment: Does your input contain empty line?? If so you can replace "" with something like "QUIT" and then type QUIT after pasting your text.

Comment: That was indeed the issue; I had some empty lines in my input text.  Using a specific escape sequence like QUIT works.

I would still much rather find a solution that doesn't require typing in an extra "okay I'm done now" keyword, especially since I believe I would have to worry about whether any of my input included the keyword with this setup.  There's really no way to tell Eclipse not to treat every newline character as a "go" sign?

Comment: You can use command line argument to pass the input surrounded by "" but that also is not ideal as your input could not contain " character. More complicated way would be using curses or even some gui toolkit.

Comment: Well, for multi-line input in a shell, it's not only PyDev you're worried about, but regular shells (where I believe you'd have the same issue right?), so, I don't see much of a way out unless you want to use something as curses (which is not supported by PyDev BTW) or a gui toolkit (or live up with the escape sequence or maybe read from the clipboard or from a file...).

Answer (score -1):

What about reading directly from the clipboard or looping over every line until it receives a termination symbol or times out. Also, is it important to make it work under Eclipse? Does it work when executed directly?